# Machine learning handling new data in every batch

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have nearly a TB of data to process. I have a field which is of tags list that video is linked to. The problem is there are plenty of tags and one video info is linked to too many tags, How can I convert it( clean it) before processing. OnehotEncoding and all other algorithms don't fit with this one.

**Example**:

```
{"user_id":1, "vid_id":101, "name":"abc", "tags":["night", "horror"], "gender":"Male"}
{"user_id":2, "vid_id":192, "name":"xyz", "tags":["action", "twins"], "gender":"Male"}
```

and so on

the above json data has so many other params too. But I wanted to use this tag params into consideration.
Now I wanted to predict the gender of the data. Help me out with the algorithms or ideas. Using Python currently and using spark to load the big data.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you expect the cleaned 'tags' output to look like?

Comment: My tags are repeated like 'java', 'JAVA', 'Java'. I wanted to clean the data before training. And if I am using NeuralNetwork, I need to convert everything to numbers. So these are the examples. @vealkind

Answer (score 0):

You can read all of your data into a sparse matrix.  The code below was built based on the brief data example you provided and will produce a sparse dictionary where each record is a row and each column is the count of how many times each term appears in the list of tags for that record.  The `vocabulary` dict will provide a mapping of terms to their column index in the final matrix.  Also, while looping across the dataset counting the tags a separate list, `targets`, is constructed with the outcome variables.  In the end you should be able to use `mat` and `targets` to train your classifier.

```
idx_pointer = [0]
indices = []
mat_data = []
vocabulary = {}
targets = []
for d in data:
    targets.append(d['gender'])
    for t in d['tags']:
        index = vocabulary.setdefault(t, len(vocabulary))
        indices.append(index)
        mat_data.append(1)
    idx_pointer.append(len(indices))

mat = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((mat_data, indices, idx_pointer), dtype=int)
```

Using the example input you provided the dense output would be a matrix like below.

```
night    horror    action    twins
1        1         0         0
0        0         1         1
```